# Dragging an app window to edge doesn't go to next desktop

Tags: finder, display, desktop, window-manager

MacBook Pro. The built-in display has two desktops and I also have connected to an external monitor with one desktop.

Dragging between *monitors* works as expected. The external monitor is "above" the built-in one, so that is dragging up or down. Using the three-finger up-swipe to invoke Mission Control works as expected, moving windows either within or across monitors.

However, I seem to have lost the ability to drag a window to the *left* or *right* edge of a desktop on the built-in display to switch it to the other desktop. **Why?** Is this doable with some setting I missed?

The window manager [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) offers keyboard shortcuts to move from one monitor to another, but it, too, doesn't seem to have **Move to another desktop on this monitor**.

Comment: Is it working as expected if you disconnect from the external monitor?

Comment: Good experiment. YES.